# Print "diagram not found" only after searching the entire file

Tags: python, file, if-statement

file.txt

```
something in 1 line
2nd line
3rd line
my_diagram with other data
some other lines
one more line
```

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    ad = fp.readlines()
    for lines in ad:
        if lines.__contains__('my_diagram'):
            print('Got it')
        else:
            print('diagram not found')
```

Every time it reads a line that doesn't have the string it prints "diagram not found". I only want to print if it's not found anywhere in the file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can add just a statement, if lines contains my diagram word, so it is means file is containing my diagrom word.

Then lets do like this:

```
found = False
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
   for lines in ad:
      if lines.contains('my diagram'):
        print("Got it")
        found = True
 if Found == False:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whlde file at once and test the condition only once :

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    if "my_diagram" in " ".join(fp.readlines()):
        print('Got it')
    else:
        print('diagram not found')
```